# MPI: Node to socket to core to process mapping (MPICH2)

Tags: mpi, mpich

Per running `MPI` on a cluster computer with say a dual socket, quad core, totaling to `8 cores`/`8 processes`, does `MPI` map this accordingly and in an orderly increment? From reading some of the `MPICH` docs, it's obvious that I can edit the machinefile(# of processes per node), however, if I value the node/program as `8 processes`, will it register that second socket or will it create an overlap and lose efficiency? Will I have to do a socket binding configuration or will `hwloc` automatically apply a solution?

Any information on this is greatly appreciated. Seems difficult to find this answer..